# Excel VBA - How to write filepath as a variable

Tags: vba, variables, path, environment-variables

I have a file saved in location A with path link C:\User\Testing\A\client_01.xlsm
But I need to open the file in location B eg. C:\User\Testing\B\client_01.xlsm where the location saved the related documents in there.
sometimes open in location C \ D etc.
So the path link save in macro needs to be variant as the location changes

Please advice as I'm beginner in VBA

Thanks

```
Sub Testing

Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

FileName = wb
FilePath = "C:\User\Testing\",FileName,"\client_01".xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: Not so clear what you want... Do you want intercalating the subfolder you name A, B - D between the folder path and workbook  name? If so, try `Dim sFld As String` `sFld = "C"` and then build the full name as `"C:\User\Testing\" & sFold & "\client_01.xlsm"`. You can test what it returns using `Debug.Print "C:\User\Testing\" & sFold & "\client_01.xlsm"` and press `Ctrl + G` to see the result in `Immediate Window`. => `"C:\User\Testing\C\client_01.xlsm"`... If the path you need is the one of the workbook **keeping the code**? If so, you should use `wb.fullName`

Comment: Try `FilePath = "C:\User\Testing\" & Left(wb.Name, InstrRev(wb.Name, ".") - 1) & "\client_01.xlsm"`.

Comment: I tried this FilePath = "C:\User\Testing\" & Left(wb.Name, InstrRev(wb.Name, ".") - 1) & "\client_01.xlsm" -> but received Ambiguous name detected

Answer (score 0):

FileName is a string so you'll have to use `wb.Name`

As for the FilePath, you can't concatenate like that, use & instead
`FilePath = "C:\User\Testing\" & FileName & "\client_01.xlsm"`

That is ofc if the workbook your code is in is called "A", "B", "C" or whatever you wanted.

If you want to use the path of the workbook that you're code is in: use something like:

```
Sub Testing

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    FileName = wb.Name
    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileName & "\client_01".xlsm"
End Sub
```

You can adjust as you see fit ofc

Answer (score 0):

To return the current workbook's folder path as a string, use:

```
FilePath = wb.Path
```

Then if your code opens to related documents (lets say their names are saved as string variables `relateddoc1` etc):

```
Workbooks.Open(FilePath & "\" & relateddoc1)
```